# Ruby how to get child class assigned key values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two classes. Base and Instance class. Base class inherited in Instance class. Am unable to get instance object key values.

```
class Base

  def save
    self.attributes
  end

end

class Instance < Base

  attr_accessor :name, :age

  def initialize(attributes={})
    attributes.keys.each do |attribute_name|
      send("#{attribute_name}=".to_sym, attributes[attribute_name])
    end
  end

end

p instance = Instance.new({:name => "local", :age => "25"})
p instance.save
p "Expected output"
# {:name => "test1", :age => "25"}

I want the above result from parent class only. I am getting following error message. 
**"NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes' for Instance:Class"**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `attributes` is rails method, so you cannot use it directly, but you can make it in a different way. I rewrite the `save` method.

```
  def save
    instance_variables.inject({}) { |sum, e| sum[e] = instance_variable_get(e);sum }
  end
```

Comment: Its doesn't help me, giving the following error
NoMethodError: undefined method `instance_values' for #<Instance:0xa3ed1 @name="test", @age="25">

Comment: @SaraVanaN Could you show the result  of `instance.methods.grep(/instance_values/)`?

Comment: I am getting empty an array []

Comment: The above save method is working now but the output is come like  {:@name=>"local", :@age=>"25"}
But no problem i can remove that @ sign. Thanks